# Notify real time wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I want to make a notify function. My issue is how to show the notification in realtime?

For example, when someone post a comment, it will show a popup for the owner immediately.

I am thinking of using ajax and recalling the request after x seconds but I don't know if this is a good idea.

Comment: if the owner will be out of website, how he will see the poppup? the best way is to send mail to owner, when somebody will be online, or will fill form. one of the easy solutions will be adding google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

For triggering a comment is done in WordPress, you can use this hook.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'show_message_function', 10, 2 );
function show_message_function( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {
    //function logic goes here for showing your popup
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

for, more information.

- [Plugin API/Action Reference/comment post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post)
- [Notification](https://wordpress.org/plugins/notification/)
- [Better Notifications for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/)